# Cauchy-Euler equation of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, cauchy-sequences

> Solve the following equation:
>   $$(x^2D^2 +4xD+2)y=e^x$$

I proceeded by using **Cauchy-Euler equation** but couldn't solve it.

Comment: Before you get help, you should work out here what you have done and we know how to help!

Comment: actually i was unable to proceed

Comment: Searching for your lecture notes or Wikipedia might help on that case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $y=\frac z {x^2}$. This would give a very simple equation

Comment: ok thanks but with whose respect will i differentiate y??? it will be a lot of help if u kindly upload the solution full..i am really sorry about my request

Comment: @mayukh. Let $y(x)=\frac{z(x)}{x^2}$

Comment: thanks so much...can u please give me suggestions on how to understand what to substitute please

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed this way:
$$(x^2D^2 +4xD+2)y=e^x$$
$$x^2y''+2xy'+2xy'+2y=e^x$$
$$(x^2y')'+(2xy)'=e^x$$
$$(x^2y'+2xy)'=e^x$$
$$(x^2y)''=e^x$$
Integrate twice.